# Is there some filter in PCL to segment kinect point cloud based on color?

Tags: kinect, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Is there some filter that allows to segment a kinect point cloud based on the rbg color of the points?

I've tried with a passthrough filter but it doesn't work with rgb, only with position. I've also found this answer explaining why.

http://www.pcl-users.org/Does-the-passthrough-filter-can-be-applied-in-PointXYZRGB-s-color-field-td3202813.html

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11823/is-there-some-filter-in-pcl-to-segment-kinect-point-cloud-based-on-color?/) by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2011-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of a recent version of PCL (maybe 1.1?), there should now be `.r`, `.g`, and `.b` fields in a `PointXYZRGB`, so it should be possible to do this.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) on 2013-05-18**:
Are you sure that is correct?  From the PCL API, rgb values seem to be combined into a single field

**Comment by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) on 2013-05-18**:
Scratch that.  .r , .g , .b can be individually accessed in PCL 1.1.0.  However, I don't think this will help with the passthrough filter